# Flask SqlAlchemy is there a way to limit the table size to n Rows

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a python app with Flask and SQL Alchemy with a sqlite3 db engine. I need to limit the tables size to 1000 rows and when this limit is reached, the oldest entry should be deleted to make room for the new one. Like in the example below:

```
|  id |   uuid   |   name   |   type   |
________________________________________
|  1  |   78c0   |   Danny  |  chef    |
|  2  |   7966   |   Mike   |  welder  |
|  .  |   ...    |   ...    |  ...     |
|1000 |   ef1b   |   John   |  fireman |
```

After the next `INSERT INTO` the table should look like:

```
|  id |   uuid   |   name   |   type   |
________________________________________
|  2  |   7966   |   Mike   |  welder  |
|  .  |   ...    |   ...    |  ...     |
|1000 |   ef1b   |   John   |  fireman |
|1001 |   7ce4   |   Fez    |  doctor  |
```

Is there a way of achieving this, when I create my models or somewhere in the config file? Let's say my models file is:

```
class People(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

Comment: I believe it is possible by using stored procedures, but they are not available in the SQLite. So you have to check this constraint manually.

Comment: Just a curiosity: where is such requirement coming from?

Comment: Storage. The table I posted was just an example, but in reality I am storing data related to some jobs (processes): PID, path to log file, time of execution, etc... and I don't need to keep a history larger than 1000 rows. The db can easily get to hundreds of GB...

Answer (score 1):

May be it is poor style but you can do something like this:

```
class People(db.Model):
    ...
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    ...

def insert_person(person):
    db.session.add(person)
    row_count = Person.query.count()
    if row_count > 1000:
        first_person = User.query.order_by(Person.timestamp.asc()).first()
        db.session.delete(first_person)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of implementing something similar but was hoping that there is some hidden SQLAlchemy setting that would do it automatically :).

Comment: actually sqlalchemy has events but when you use one of before_insert or after_insert event it doesnt allow to make a chance, it close session so you cant do.